# What aria label should I use for 'inactive' items in a list that the user can still interact with?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a list of data in a visualisation and I want to make it as accessible as possible. There are two lists next to each other.

The list items has two states. Multiple rows can be active or inactive. A single row could be selected.

Selecting something in one list, will show 'related' items as active, and inactive. See the simplified example below. The user has selected "A 2", which is linked to "B 1" and "B 4", so A2 is `aria-selected` but there's no `aria-active` or `aria-inactive`, I thought to use `aria-disabled` as demonstrated - BUT does this not indicate that it is not interactable? The user can still click on the disabled item to then select it.

Would it be better to do multiple `aria-selected`, and a single `aria-current=true` on the single 'selected' item? Would it be odd that if the user hasn't yet made a selection and everything is 'active', every item will be `aria-selected=true`?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px
}

.list div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background: grey;
}

.list .selected {
  background: red;
}

.list .inactive {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div role="row">A 1</div>
    <div role="row" class="selected" aria-selected="true">A 2</div>
    <div role="row">A 3</div>
    <div role="row">A 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div role="row">B 1</div>
    <div role="row" class="inactive" aria-disabled="true">B 2</div>
    <div role="row" class="inactive" aria-disabled="true">B 3</div>
    <div role="row">B 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clarifications from comments. Here is how the actual implementation looks with an item selected:
[image], it's quite complex so I tried to distil it down to the specific issue.

1. *Like per each list is it one-to-many that may be selected at one time?* Only one item can be 'selected', like in the example. Multiple items are 'highlighted' or 'active'. When nothing is selected, they are all 'active'.
2. *How do the lists correlate to one another? How do they correlate to content they may be providing?*
   The items have a spline in between, connecting each other that I've given them a `role="presentation"`. There's actually a timeline inbetween, and things are only 'active' if the items in the timeline share the item in the other list?
3. *If there's content changing to reflect their relationships that may need to consider things like aria-atomic updating dependent upon aria-relevant correlations, etc?*
   I was considering this. The items change only if you scroll, the only thing that changes otherwise is the active/highlight and selected state.

I hadn't considered an `aria-label`, I think that might be the best solution because the user can click and select the inactive item.

Comment: So `aria-active` wouldn't apply here as it's not a tab role I assume, and `aria-selected` wouldn't be valid either without a declared or inferred role. I'd suggest instead providing an `role="group"` to the respective groups with `aria-current` or `aria-activedescendant` instead, but left as a comment until I can come back when not multi-tasking between builds and actually think it over lol since a list element and other things need considered. However bravo for trying to be WCAG-WAI!

Comment: I would have thought [`aria-disabled`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-disabled) would be the closest match for what you're looking for, but if you want a little more control have you considered using [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-label) to tell the user directly that an option is currently inactive?

Comment: Can you explain more about how this is intended to behave? Is it correct to say you have a 2D grid of items, any (and only) one of which can be selected at a time, but some other items become "active" if they're related to the selected item?

Comment: Ok yea so like Sean I think's asking if you could elaborate just a bit more on the use-case here that would be helpful to ensure we're understanding correctly. Like per each list is it one-to-many that may be selected at one time? How do the lists correlate to one another? How do they correlate to content they may be providing? If there's content changing to reflect their relationships that may need to consider things like `aria-atomic` updating dependent upon `aria-relevant` correlations, etc? Some more [insight](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) would be helpful depending on desired rating.

Comment: ARIA usage can be complicated and there are some comments that are muddying the water from the original request so I'll try to clear that up. First, `aria-active` does not exist. Not sure where that came from. Second, `aria-selected` **is** valid in this situation since the element has `role="row"`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-selected. Third, `aria-atomic` and `aria-relevant` are for live regions, which does not come into play in this situation. But I agree more clarification is needed. The term "inactive" in the OP is confusing. Sounds like Inactive does not mean `aria-disabled`

Comment: Without further clarification, I currently agree with @MarkHanna that an `aria-label` will probably help.  (Technically, I'd use an `aria-labelledby`, with a hidden `<span>` on the page with the text "inactive" and then specify the ID of that span in the aria-labelledby of all the list items that are inactive.)

Comment: Aria-disabled indicates that you can't interact with the element. If you still can interact while the element is said inactive, then you shouldn't use it. Adding a precision in the label is probably the best, but be careful that aria-label/aria-labelledby **replaces** the text present in the element it is set on rather than appending it up.

Comment: Added some clarification and a screenshot of the real implementation that should hopefully clear things up a little. I think `aria-label` might be the best solution!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have plans to make the visualized data (e.g. the Sankey-like flow widths) accessible as well?

Comment: @Sean I'd like to make as much accessible as possible, but I worried the splines would be difficult to describe/interact with effectively using a screen reader. I could give them an `aria-label` with a source, and destination?

Comment: I think it may be easier and more clear to dynamically represent the state of the visualization in text form, with text descriptions of the splines as a tree of nested list items. If you ask a new question related to this, I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a semantics and accessibility point of view, I'd consider separating out the controls from the visualization itself—at least in terms of the markup. This will let you use more semantic input elements, like `<input type="radio">`, which come with their own states that assistive tech understands. And it will keep selection state (which is an input element trait) separate from highlighted state (which is a visualization display trait).

You can then tie those input elements to the visualization using the `aria-controls` attribute.

To denote the state of the items in the visualization itself, instead of using ARIA roles, I would suggest just using text.

A basic example could work something like this:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let targets = e.target.dataset.controls.split(' ')
    items.forEach(item => {
      let index = targets.indexOf(item.id)
      if (-1 === index) item.dataset.state = 'inactive'
      else if (0 === index) item.dataset.state = 'selected'
      else item.dataset.state = 'highlighted'
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto / auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
form,
figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto/auto auto 1fr;
  gap: 1ch;
}
fieldset {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto/auto auto;
}
input,
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
figure,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin: 1ch 0 0 1ch;
  padding: 1ch;
}
li[data-state="inactive"] {
  background: #ddd;
}
li[data-state="selected"] {
  background: #aaffaa;
}
li[data-state="highlighted"] {
  background: #aaaaff;
}
li[data-state="inactive"] span,
li[data-state="highlighted"] span.selected {
  display: none;
}
li[data-state="selected"] span,
li[data-state="highlighted"] span.highlighted {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h2>Controls</h2>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>List A</legend>
    <input id="input-A1" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A1 item-B2 item-B3" />
    <label for="input-A1">A1</label>
    <input id="input-A2" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A2 item-B1" />
    <label for="input-A2">A2</label>
    <input id="input-A3" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A3 item-B2 item-B3 item-B4" />
    <label for="input-A3">A3</label>
    <input id="input-A4" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A4 item-B2" />
    <label for="input-A4">A4</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>List B</legend>
    <input id="input-B1" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B1 item-A2 item-A3 item-A4" />
    <label for="input-B1">B1</label>
    <input id="input-B2" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B2 item-A2 item-B3" />
    <label for="input-B2">B2</label>
    <input id="input-B3" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B3 item-A1 item-A4" />
    <label for="input-B3">B3</label>
    <input id="input-B4" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B4 item-A2" />
    <label for="input-B4">B4</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<h2>Visualization</h2>
<figure id="graphic" aria-live="polite">
  <ul aria-label="List A">
    <li class="item" id="item-A1" data-state="inactive">A1<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A2" data-state="inactive">A2<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A3" data-state="inactive">A3<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A4" data-state="inactive">A4<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul aria-label="List B">
    <li class="item" id="item-B1" data-state="inactive">B1<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B2" data-state="inactive">B2<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B3" data-state="inactive">B3<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B4" data-state="inactive">B4<span class="selected">, selected</span><span class="highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

But you probably want the visualization to be directly manipulatable by clicking on the items themselves. If so, you could keep the same structure as the first example, but visually hide the accessible controls and text, and trigger the controls whenever a user clicks on an item in the visualization.

Again, this still has the form controls which are responsible for controlling state—they're just visually hidden:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let targets = e.target.dataset.controls.split(' ')
    items.forEach(item => {
      let index = targets.indexOf(item.id)
      if (-1 === index) item.dataset.state = 'inactive'
      else if (0 === index) item.dataset.state = 'selected'
      else item.dataset.state = 'highlighted'
    })
  })
})
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let inputId = 'input-' + e.target.id.split('-')[1]
    document.getElementById(inputId).click()
  })
})
```

```css
.sr-only {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto/auto auto 1fr;
  gap: 1ch;
}
figure,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin: 1ch 0 0 1ch;
  padding: 1ch;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
li[data-state="inactive"] {
  background: #ddd;
}
li[data-state="selected"] {
  background: #aaffaa;
}
li[data-state="highlighted"] {
  background: #aaaaff;
}
li[data-state="inactive"] span,
li[data-state="highlighted"] span.selected {
  display: none;
}
li[data-state="selected"] span,
li[data-state="highlighted"] span.highlighted {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="sr-only">
  <h2>Controls</h2>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>List A</legend>
      <input id="input-A1" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A1 item-B2 item-B3"/>
      <label for="input-A1">A1</label>
      <input id="input-A2" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A2 item-B1"/>
      <label for="input-A2">A2</label>
      <input id="input-A3" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A3 item-B2 item-B3 item-B4"/>
      <label for="input-A3">A3</label>
      <input id="input-A4" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-A4 item-B2"/>
      <label for="input-A4">A4</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>List B</legend>
      <input id="input-B1" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B1 item-A2 item-A3 item-A4"/>
      <label for="input-B1">B1</label>
      <input id="input-B2" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B2 item-A2 item-B3"/>
      <label for="input-B2">B2</label>
      <input id="input-B3" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B3 item-A1 item-A4"/>
      <label for="input-B3">B3</label>
      <input id="input-B4" type="radio" name="input" aria-controls="graphic" data-controls="item-B4 item-A2"/>
      <label for="input-B4">B4</label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<h2 class="sr-only">Visualization</h2>
<figure id="graphic" aria-live="polite">
  <ul aria-label="List A">
    <li class="item" id="item-A1" data-state="inactive">A1<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A2" data-state="inactive">A2<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A3" data-state="inactive">A3<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-A4" data-state="inactive">A4<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul aria-label="List B">
    <li class="item" id="item-B1" data-state="inactive">B1<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B2" data-state="inactive">B2<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B3" data-state="inactive">B3<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
    <li class="item" id="item-B4" data-state="inactive">B4<span class="sr-only selected">, selected</span><span class="sr-only highlighted">, highlighted</span></li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to have content that is simply hidden for non screen reader users, that's a great idea, much cleaner a mess of `aria` tags. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I believe the solution to your problem is to use tab index. You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

In short you can use tabindex="-1" to remove an element from the natural tab order, but the element can still be focused by calling its focus() method.

Edit:
I probably missed mentioning why setting tab-index could be needed. For accessibility, when using interactive lists, one should consider the fact that the UI should be navigable using the keyboard as well. For this setting the tab-index for active and inactive elements will help.

However, probably should have mentioned the use of `aria-live='polite'`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) to regions with dynamic contents. This will let the screen reader watch for changes in that region and announce it. In addition you can use [role='list'] or [role='group'] to provide additional context to screen readers about the list.

Comment: Please read the question more closely. This is not what they want.